# How to use input validation laravel as a function?

Tags: laravel, validation

For example, how to use input validation in laravel `'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'` as a function and return its **true** or **false**? can we?
If can't, what is the best way to check for any input to specific column is unique as a function?

Comment: Why not check the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: I did, but I just get the idea now, from **Determining If Messages Exist For A Field** I should use `->errors();` instead of using `->validate();` thanks sir @BrianGlaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators) and [over here](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html) I will try to give an example below.

```
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'unique:users,email_address',
        ]);

        // To get the boolean just simply use this:
        $email_bool = $validator->passes();

        // $email_bool now contains a boolean testing only the unique rule of email.
    }
}
```

You could also of course just use `$validation->fails()`, but this will of course yield the negative of `$validation->passes()`.

So basically, you just make a custom validation rule, a very specific one. Then you just test it on your data, and convert it into a boolean with a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

You can also check unique value in controller like:

```
$chkUniqueEmailId = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
if(!empty($chkUniqueEmailId)){
 return redirect()->route('auth.register')->withFlashDanger("This Email address is already exists.");
}
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks for your alternative way :)

Comment: @IkhsanWisnuadjiGamadarenda you like my answer then please give up vote